# Filling in small detail in simple proof regarding measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know it's been asked before but I want to try a method that I haven't seen here before.

We know that $g:[a, b] \to \mathbb R^n$ is Lipschitz. Assume $n>1$.

We want to show that $g([a, b])$ has zero measure.

I want to use the theorem that says Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ maps zero measure sets to zero measure sets.

Intuitively speaking, $[a, b]$ has zero measure in $\mathbb R^n$ and so this should be straightforward and simple.

But if we want to be rigorous, $[a, b]$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and so we can't say it has zero measure there. Infact, since it is not a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, we can't really talk about our $g$ function as an endormorphism of $\mathbb R^n$.

What we can do is define $S:= \{(x, 0, \dots ,0): x\in \mathbb [a, b]\}$ and then talk about $g^*: S \to \mathbb R^n$ and I would agree that we can use the theorem I mentioned above. But $g^*$ is not $g$ and $S$ is not $[a, b]$. Is there any way to "iron out" this little detail and make this proof correct using this theorem? It kind of begs to be used, but it does not seem to fit exactly.

Comment: Are you assuming  $n>1$?

Comment: Which step is bothering you? Defining $g^*$? Or that the image of $g^*$ is the image of $g$?

Comment: @kimchilover I forgot, yes that's true. Assume $n > 1$. Dap what's bothering me is how to use this theorem. Using it on $S$ and $g^*$ does not help us with $[a, b]$ and $g$ which is what we originally wanted.

Comment: 1. Define $g^*(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = g(x_1)$. 2. Verify $g^*$ is Lipschitz: $d(g^*(P),g^*(P'))=d(g(x_1),g(x'_1)) \leq C |x_1-x'_1| \leq C d(P,P')$. 3. Verify $g^*(S)=g([a,b])$: immediate.

Comment: @ZachTeitler the problem with this argument is that $g(x_1)$ is not always defined, as $g$ is defined on $[a, b]$ but $g^*$ is defined on $\mathbb R^n$, so the first coordinate need not be on $[a, b]$.

Comment: @OriaGruber Thank you. Step $1-\epsilon$, then, is to extend $g$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = g(a)$ for $x<a$ and $g(x)=g(b)$ for $x>b$. Then I believe it should be easy to check that the extended $g$ is still Lipschitz (even with the same Lipschitz constant).

Answer (score 0):

A tiny variation of Zach Teitler's comment: Define $\bar g:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R^n $ by $\bar g(x) = g(a)$ if $x<a$, by $\bar g(x)=g(b) $ if $x>b$, and by $\bar g(x) = g(x)$ otherwise.  Now define $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ by $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \bar g(x_1).$  It is easy to see that $\bar g$ and hence $f$ are Lipschitz.  Let $S=\{(x_1,0,\ldots,0)\in\mathbb R^n: a\le x_1\le b\}$ be the line segment connecting $(a,0,\ldots,0)$ to $(b,0,\ldots,0).$ If $n>1$, the Lebesgue measure of $S$ is zero.  But the sets $g([a,b])$ and $f(S)$ are equal, and so the measure of $g([a,b])$ is zero.